# Boolean put in a PendingIntent for an AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I have a boolean that I put in an intent. Then a pendingIntent is created using this intent used for an AlarmManager. When I create my AlarmManager, I first create the intent, then put the boolean in the intent with the method putExtra() and then set my AlarmManager with the pending intent. Imagine that actually, I need the value of this boolean at the time the alarm rings not when I set up the AlarmManager. Do you have an idea how to do it?

Here is my current code taking the boolean at the moment the alarm is set up (where isGameActivated is an the boolean attribute of the class):

```
public void setAlarmManager(int index, String sound, String title) {
    Intent intent_to_alarm_ring = new Intent(this, AlarmRing.class);
    intent_to_alarm_ring.putExtra("activate_game", isGameActivated); //This is the boolean I am talking about
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, index, intent_to_alarm_ring,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmsMinutes.get(index));
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmsHours.get(index));
    if (cal.getTime().before(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())) {
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    }

    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: you are calling `setAlarmManager()` with the same `index` (actually it is the second arg in `getActivity` that needs to be unique)

Comment: Yes I know but actually it is a part of my whole code. I didn't want to write everything...I just wanted to focus on the boolean problem...

Comment: then use different value in `getActivity`

Comment: The second arg in getActivity comes from the parameter of the method setAlarmManager. In an another place if the code, I avoid to have dulplicate value of this index

Comment: so did you try to use unique `requestCode` anytime you call `getActivity()`? (just increment it or something...)

Comment: Yes :) the request code is always unique when I call getActivity() :)

Comment: so whats your current code now?

Comment: THe same. Just, whenever I call the method setAlarmManager(int index, String title),knowing that the index has to be unique because it is the requestCode, I prevent this index to be duplicate (so it is unique)

Comment: ah, ok i see it now, so if the value of `isGameActivated` changes over the time so why do you want to pass it as a static "extra"? thy not to get it directly from target activity?

Comment: I use this boolean for other purpose in other parts of the code. But when I change the activity (from the current one to the new one), I want to have access to this boolean in the new activityat the moment thactivity is changing. (I hope I am clear lol)

Comment: This might help you-
There is two scenario:
1. if your activity is open 
Add
   protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        boolean b = intent.getBooleanExtra("activate_game", false)
    }

2 if activity was finished
in your onCreate method
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            boolean b = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("activate_game", false)
        }

Comment: I do not think that the problem comes from getting the Boolean since the Boolean I put(with intent.putExtra) is not the one I want. Indeed, Let s call t1= the time I put the Boolean in the intent and t2 the time of the alarm. For now, I am putting b in the intent at the time t1 whereas I want to put it later, at the time t2 event if the intent is created at the time t1...Not sure I am clear haha